# What part of speech is "sitting"?

Tags: grammar, parts-of-speech

1. look at the man sitting on the bus.
2. he decided to abandon his subway seat in favor of a woman standing nearby.

What parts of speech are "sitting" and "standing"?

Comment: They are present participles used as adjectives. They are part of reduced relative clauses ("who is sitting" and "who is standing") modifying "man" and "woman" respectively. Have a look at the [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/). Your question might do better there.

Comment: Individual words don't have parts of speech outside of sentences they're used in. Inflected forms of verbs like _sits_ or _sat_ or _sitting_ are usually thought of as verbs, but the Romans, [who invented the 8 parts of speech](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/don.html), considered Participles like _sitting_ or _thrown_ to be their own part of speech, and not verbs at all.

Comment: @fev You mean used as modifiers, not as adjectives.

Comment: @tchrist Yes, you are right, should have said modifiers. "Running" would be an adjective in "running" water. The OP's example is different.

Comment: @fev Maybe, maybe not. It fails several syntactic tests normally used to identify adjectives such as gradability. Most people can't say they have very running water.

Comment: They are both gerund-participle **verb** forms. The non-finite gerund-participial clause "sitting on the bus" has the same meaning as the relative clause "who is sitting on the bus" -- they both modify "man". And the gerund-participial clause "standing nearby" means the same as "who is standing nearby" -- they both modify "woman".

Comment: Incidentally, despite what was said in a comment above, virtually all words belong to just one part of speech, irrespective of whether in isolation or part of a sentence. There are only a very few words that belong to more than one part of speech depending on their function in the sentence.